# How to conditionally filter an array of objects that includes duplicates in Javascripts

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like following, some commands share the same text:

```
const Commands=[
{
  id: "id1",
  text: "read",
  message: "read",
},
{
  id: "id2",
  text: "read",
  message: "read a book",
},
{
  id: "id3",
  text: "sleep",
  message: "sleep",
},
{
  id: "id4",
  text: "help",
  message: "help",
},
{
  id: "id5",
  text: "help",
  message: "command help",
},
]
```

I want to filter this array out based on the user input message. Also, for the commands that have the same text, I only want the first one (or the default one). For example, if the user input ["read a book"], the result would be

```
[
{
  id: "id2",
  text: "read",
  message: "read a book",
},
{
  id: "id3",
  text: "sleep",
  message: "sleep",
},
{
  id: "id4",
  text: "help",
  message: "help",
},
]
```

if the user input ["read a message"], which does not exist in the array, the default one will be returned, the result would be

```
[
{
  id: "id1",
  text: "read",
  message: "read",
},
{
  id: "id3",
  text: "sleep",
  message: "sleep",
},
{
  id: "id4",
  text: "help",
  message: "help",
},
]
```

Here is my JavaScripts/TypeScripts,

```
const defaultReadText =
    Commands.find(
      (command) => command.message === userReadMessage
    )?.text ?? "read"
  const defaultReadMessage =
    Commands.find(
      (command) => command.message === userReadMessage
    )?.message ?? "read"

const defaultHelpText =
    Commands.find(
      (command) => command.message === userHelpMessage
    )?.text ?? "help"
  const defaultHelpMessage =
    Commands.find(
      (command) => command.message === userHelpMessage
    )?.message ?? "help"

 const enabledCommands =
    Commands.filter(
        (command) =>
          (command.text === defaultReadText &&
            command.message === defaultReadMessage) ||
          command.text != defaultReadText
      )?.filter(
        (command) =>
          (command.text === defaultHelpText &&
            command.message === defaultHelpMessage) ||
          command.text != defaultHelpText
      )
```

I wonder if there is better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `text` and take the object for a matching message.

```js
const
    filter = (array, message) => Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.text] || o.message === message) r[o.text] = o;
        return r;
    }, {})),
    commands = [{ id: "id1", text: "read", message: "read" }, { id: "id2", text: "read", message: "read a book" }, { id: "id3", text: "sleep", message: "sleep" }, { id: "id4", text: "help", message: "help" }, { id: "id5", text: "help", message: "command help" }];

console.log(filter(commands));
console.log(filter(commands, "read a book"));
console.log(filter(commands, "read a message"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A chainable approach with `reduce`

```js
const
    filter = message => (r, o) => {
        if (r[r.length - 1]?.text === o.text) {
            if (o.message === message) r[r.length - 1] = o;
        } else {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    },
    commands = [{ id: "id1", text: "read", message: "read" }, { id: "id2", text: "read", message: "read a book" }, { id: "id3", text: "sleep", message: "sleep" }, { id: "id4", text: "help", message: "help" }, { id: "id5", text: "help", message: "command help" }];

console.log(commands.reduce(filter(), []));
console.log(commands.reduce(filter("read a book"), []));
console.log(commands.reduce(filter("read a message"), []));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. But the chainable one seems work if the array is sorted by the text field. If I move the object of "read a book" to the end, it won't work, still return both "read" object. Also, I think I may need to add another boolean field to define with command is the default one, otherwise, whichever is the first one in the sorted array will be considered as the default.

Comment: right. it's up to you.